# Driving 8 ohm headphones with DAC

Tags: impedance, dac, headphones, audio-codec

I have stereo differential (meaning each left and right speaker have 2 wires) headphones. The specs say that impedance of headphones is 8 ohms. I need to drive this headphones with a dac with built-in headphone driver. 
  All the dac chips i have searched (from analog devices(adau1772) and asahi kasei(ak4373) )  which can drive differential left and right channels have mentioned in datasheets that this chip can drive 16,24 and 32 ohm headphones. I cant find a dac or audio codec which says it can drive 8 ohm headphones.
My questions are :
1) can i be wrong in understanding the specs of differential stereo headphones? Can two 8 ohm speakers add up impedance to 16 ohms?
2) if we assume that headphones impedance is 8 ohms, what will happen if I drive this headphones with chip whose datasheet says it supports minimum headphones impedance of 16 ohms?
3) can you suggest any dac or audio codec chip which can drive 8 ohm differential headphones?

Comment: 8 ohm headphones are uncommon - can you give a link to a datasheet for them?

Comment: Is there space to isolate with Voltage Follower's to change impedance ?

Comment: Just add an 8 ohm resistor in series for each speaker. The loss is only 3 dB, which is not much in audio terms.

Comment: @Andrew mortan: no datasheet is available.

Comment: @optionparty: i chose adau1772 codec. I first need to connect headphones with its evaluation board. So I can say i can add an additional pcb between headphones and evaluation board.

Comment: @whatroughbeast: can you please tell do i need to add 2 resistors in series for each channel? One end of resistor with left channel p and other end with output of dac driver?

Comment: "Just add an 8 ohm resistor in series for each speaker."